# Is there an increasing function which sometimes has negative derivative?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function *f* : [*a, b*]--> ℝ which is continuous on [*a, b*] and differentiable on (*a, b*) I am looking for a counterexample to disprove the following statement:

> If *f*  is increasing, then *f'(x)* ≥ 0 for every x in the open interval (a,b).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What makes you believe that such a counterexample exists?

Comment: If $x\in(a,b)$ with $f'(x)<0$, there is an $h>0$ with $x+h<b$ and ${f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}<0$. What does this tell you?

Answer (score 2):

Let *h* > 0. If *f* is increasing, then we have

*f*(*x* + *h*) ≥ *f*(*x*)

=> *f*(*x* + *h*) - *f*(*x*) ≥ 0

=> *hf'*(*x*) + *o*(*h*) ≥ 0

=> *f'*(*x*) ≥ 0

So no such function exists; the statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is actually true.

Let $x$ $\in$ $]a,b[$. As $x<b$, $\exists$ $\epsilon > 0$ / $x < \epsilon < b$. Now:

$x < \epsilon$ and f is increasing $\Rightarrow$ $f(x) < f(\epsilon)$

This gives $f(x) - f(\epsilon) < 0$. But $x - \epsilon < 0$, so dividing both sides:

$\frac{f(x) - f(\epsilon)}{x - \epsilon} > 0$

Letting $\epsilon$ approach x, we get:

$\lim_{\epsilon\to x^+}$ $\frac{f(x) - f(\epsilon)}{x - \epsilon} \ge 0$

In a similar manner:

$\lim_{\epsilon\to x^-}$ $\frac{f(x) - f(\epsilon)}{x - \epsilon} \ge 0$

This shows that:

$\lim_{\epsilon\to x}$ $\frac{f(x) - f(\epsilon)}{x - \epsilon} \ge 0$

i.e. $f'(x) \ge 0$. But $x$ was arbitrary. Therefore etc.